# How does one deserialize a Firestore Blob type in Swift (iOS, macOS, ipadOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple object in a Firestore database that I want to deserialize into a Swift struct. It consists of an ID string, a timestamp which is a Firestore Timestamp, and a Firestore Blob for the value.

I have an `Item` object in `Item.swift` which has the same fields.

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Item: Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var timestamp: Timestamp
    var val: [UInt8]
}
```

I want to deserialize the Item data from the Firestore database into my Swift object.

```
let items = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> Item in
    let data = document.data()
    let itemId = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
    let itemTimestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
    let itemVal = data["val"] as? [UInt8] ?? []
    return Item(id: itemId, encoding: itemEncoding, timestamp: itemTimestamp, val: itemVal)
}
```

What type should `val` be in order to deserialize a Firestore Blob into it? I can get the ID and the Timestamp no problem, but the Blob is evading me. I have tried `[UInt8]` as shown above in the code snippets, but I always get an empty array (indicating that it was unable to coerce `data["val"]` into a `[UInt8]`.

When I print the `data["val"]` directly, I get values like this

```
Optional(<789ccb4b 2ccb4c4f 2cc92fd2 4bcec92c 48ca4f2c 4ad12b2f ca2c490d 49ad28d1 00d2b99a 00fb920d a8>)
Optional(<789cf34c 53a8cc2f 5548cec9 4cce56c8 2cd10162 85e2d4bc 94621d85 a4d21220 ef51c3cc 62854485 9ccc9292 9c5485ac c4bc6c00 d58612ab>)
Optional(<789c05c1 b1118020 1045c156 5e051461 66606603 8cf3e508 14c63b06 eddedd65 04d374b3 72b4fe11 7a83f369 174a2551 37b9e722 76133d7b 88b07a17 dcda7446 4ffcff59 16f0>)
Optional(<789ccb28 292928b6 d2d74fce c92c28ae ccd34b4e d657d607 00561f07 43>)
```

The [Javascript documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Blob) for Blob is quite clear on how to convert to and from byte arrays and base64 encoded strings, but I don't see anything similar for the Swift documentation, and I don't see any Blob type available in the Swift SDK.

Am I missing something very obvious? What is the proper Swift data type to store a Blob in when deserializing?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780158-init

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is no need to convert to and from byte arrays and Blob objects with Swift like you do for Javascript.

The type is Swift's generic `Data` type (or `NSData` if you need that for some reason).

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Item: Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var timestamp: Timestamp
    var val: Data
}
```

and you can deserialize into that object with similar code as to what is posted in the question

```
let items = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> Item in
    let data = document.data()
    let itemId = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
    let itemTimestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
    let itemVal = data["val"] as? Data ?? Data()
    return Item(id: itemId, encoding: itemEncoding, timestamp: itemTimestamp, val: itemVal)
}
```

`Data` is basically a higher level object backed by a `[UInt8]` so you should probably just use it directly, but if you really need a `[UInt8]` you can convert between them quite easily.

```
// instantiate an array of bytes
let bytes: [UInt8] = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 98, 121, 116, 101, 115]

// coerce [UInt8] into Data
let someData: Data = Data(bytes)

// coerce Data into [UInt8]
let someBytes: [UInt8] = Array(someData)
```